# Escalabilidad Apps

Tags: android, base-de-datos, nodejs, postgresql, servidor

No tengo mucho conocimiento sobre servidores y modelos de negocios para apps. Desarrolle una app que tiene por el momento 9 usuarios estos ingresan desde la app de android o la web.

Tengo un VPS SSD en ovh.com y sus caracteristicas son:

1. 1 core a 2.4 Ghz
2. 2 GB de ram
3. 10GB de ssd
4. 100 Mbps - Tráfico ilimitado
   [mas info](https://www.ovh.com/world/es/vps/vps-ssd.xml)

El Back-end usa Mqtt, node.js y postgresql, ademas almacena fotos y pdf de algunos reportes.

mi pregunta es si en un futuro lejano o cercano tuviese mas de 1 millon de clientes, como escalaria mi app en el servidor?

mis dudas son:

> 1. Deberia usar un servidor para la db, otro para almacenar las fotos y pdf y otro para el codigo del back-end como balanceador. (cluster)
> 2. Podría usar un cloud computed y assignar ram, almacenamiento y cpu de acorde obtenga clientes.

Si tienen mas recomendaciones y/o concejos se los agradeceria, tambien si conocen de otros proveedores que puedan suplir con mi app y mi problema de escalabilidad se lo agradeceria.

Comment: para la escalabilidad tienes amazon web services, google engine, incluso firebase que realmente esta diseñado para estos menesteres

Comment: Hola amigo, gracias hay una parte de mi app y es generar reportes en PDF esto como lo lograría ya que firebase por lo que ví me ofrece base de datos y almacenamiento. Donde podré colocar mi código que hace esto. Y en Amazon de todo lo que ofrece que me serviría EC2? U otro

Comment: Una cosa es el almacenamiento y otra procesar los datos, para ello debes montarte un servidor con codigo como php para procesar los datos y generar los pdf

Answer (score 0):

te explico los servidores de base de datos usualmente van separados por defecto del servidor de tu app (son dos computadoras diferentes), es la arquitectura que va por defecto si tu servidor, por lo menos si vas a tener millones de usuarios como tu calificas deberías de tener unas mejores características a mi parecer, aunque si tienes un muy pero muy buen diseño de tu aplicación del lado del servidor puede que te sirva (en pocas palabras creo que 15% es la probabilidad de que te sirva esas características).

Tienes que suponer que si tienes 1M de usuarios al menos el 50% de dichos usuarios debería de estar conectado en simultaneo, esperas aproximadamente 500K personas, son muy bajos recursos para una buena app, tu servidor ira muy lento o terminaría colapsando.

Sabiendo que actualmente estas empezando, deberías empezar con algo de bajos recursos luego puedes ir agregando características adicionales a tu servidor (puedes migrarlo, cambiarlo de VPS, ETC.) para empezar considero que esta bien.

Te recomiendo que veas las opciones de hosting que tiene AZURE tienen buena relación funcionalidad | precio.

Bueno estas son mis consideraciones, espero te sirvan de algo.

Comment: Hola, gracias estuve bien en azure pero entre virtual machines y app service cual me serviría?

Comment: te recomiendo un appservices antes que un virtual machine, debido a que solo requieres una app(cosas mas basicas, tambien es mas facil de configurar), las virtual machine te las recomendaria para escritorios remotos y funciones avanzadas es como tener una pc siempre encendida (ademas que creo que cobran mas), es preferible un servicio de aplicacion (appServices) que una virtual machine.